# Need to fetch value from array for each index in MAT

Tags: mat, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Need to fetch value from array for each in MAT

```
SELECT a.table[0].value.specVersion.value FROM OBJECTS 742325 a
```

In above query, i am able to get the value on specific index but i want run in loop to fetch value for every index in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
SELECT b.value.specVersion.value from OBJECTS (SELECT a.table[0:-1] FROM OBJECTS 742325 a) b
```

should work, though it doesn't give you the array index.
The inner select gives you the array contents, the outer one then steps through the contents.